# SVG-based animation does not run in <img> tag until another <svg> with an <image> as child is added to DOM

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm struggling to understand a really strange phenomenon. I've got an svg-based shimmer effect (that has a filter and animation) that I'm rendering in the DOM via an img tag.

The shimmer effect does not actually come into effect, not until I add the same svg as a separate svg with an image element that gets the src of the above img tag.

This is a bit difficult to explain, so here's a JS Fiddle that showcases this behavior in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/x3w05c7h/101/

Here is what I'm trying to render:

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 700 475'%3E%3Cfilter id='b' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='20'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Cimage preserveAspectRatio='none' filter='url%28%23b%29' x='0' y='0' height='100%25' width='100%25' href='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
```

If you paste the above in an html document, you will see a blurred gray image but without any animation.

However, if you then add this in the html as well:

```html
<svg xmlns='http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 700 475'><filter id='b' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='20'/></filter><image preserveAspectRatio='none' filter='url(#b)' x='0' y='0' height='100%' width='100%' href='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'/></svg>
```

The animation will start working.

To reiterate: if only the top-most img element is in the DOM (and the second svg tag is commented out), the shimmer effect does not animate. But once you un-comment the svg tag (which has an image rendering the same data), the shimmer starts working for the img tag above.

I need someone to explain why this is happening, and how to make the shimmer effect run for the img tag without needing to add the additional svg.

I've tried using the svg in utf-8 format (instead of base64), I've tried playing around with the gaussian filter, but to no avail.

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Done, I've added the code/text inside the question itself.

Comment: You haven't yet made it an SO snippet. Click the links above, or take it from click the [<>] button in the SO editor